# SAX parsing using DefaultHandler converts all text to lowercase

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I am using DefaultHandler to parse out InputStream which is XML based. It works fine but with one exception. All the characters are converted to lowercase.
For example if my xml has a element like VALUE, what I see after parsing is value(instead of VALUE).
Any clues how can I get the values in parsing the original case ( Uppercase instead of lowercase ) ?

```
public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName) throws SAXException {
    try {
         if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("taga")){
          System.err.println("value parsed .. "+_objBuffer.toString());

   }
   catch (Exception e) {}

}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    try{
            _objBuffer.append(ch, start, length);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about `DefaultHandler`? The SAX interface itself does nothing with character case, and no standard XML code should be doing this, as case is significant in XML (unlike HTML).

Comment: @Francis, Have updated the code above which I am using to parse, would you require some other information as well ?

Comment: You should consider the options you set for your XML parser. Maybe there is something telling it to use lowercase for everything.

Comment: This is how I am configuring the parser and I can not understand which option is converting everything to lowercase

  SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  spf.setValidating(false);
  spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
  SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
  parser.parse(xmlstream, mySaxParser);

Comment: Set a breakpoint in characters() to see which parser you are actually getting and look at the configuration for that. I can't see anything obvious in what you have posted.

Comment: How are you certain that the data is being converted to lowercase? I have never seen this problem in Java's SAX implementation. Is this the case for all event handlers (startElement(), endElement(), characters(), etc, etc)? Did you try setting breakpoints and look at the value of the parameters?

Comment: You are displaying character data and not the element name. In your question it looks like your talking about element names. Are you sure you're watching the right thing ? You could copy/paste all your code and the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check an implementation function `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Probably you should use `equals()` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase()`.